# How to log the Ram and CPU usage for Linux Processes

Tags: linux, process, cpu, ram

How would I track the CPU and Ram usage for a process that may run, stop, and then re-run with a different PID?

I am looking to track this information for all processes on a Linux server but the problem is when the process stops and restarts, it will have a different PID and I am not sure how to identify it as the same process.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for here is called "process accounting".

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the command of the process, just pipe it to a [grep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) like this:

```
ps ux | grep yourcommandgoeshere
```

Comment: I want to be able to track all processes for all users.  What if two users are running a program with the same name?

Comment: In this case the command will return both processes. Just play around with ps, it can be adapted in many ways: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can [setup a crontab](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) to record output of commands like

1. top -b -n1 | grep
2. ps ux | grep

Alternatively, you can use [sealion](https://sealion.com) service. By simply installing agent and configuring it according to your needs in simple steps, you can see output of the executed commands online.

Hope it helps...